# What is the UI control and toolkit used for the IE 10 download list.

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a windows desktop app, one element of which is a list view of items, perhaps twenty items long at most (usually more like one or two or three). The Downloads window of IE 10 provides a very close approximation of what I'd ideally like to see instead of my current gory looking DataGridView solution. Can anyone provide insight into what UI toolkit IE uses and what controls are in this window? Is it totally custom a-la Office?

[image: IE "View Downloads" window]

Comment: That is VERY easy to do using templates in `WPF`. But then again you're using WinForms, so...

Comment: IE is a native program and they have their own UI library (which is why IE10 uses Windows 8-style buttons, even on Windows 7). It is not exposed in any libraries to third-party consumers.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Any suggestions for someone who hasn't ever used WPF? A templates tutorial or something close? I'm not opposed to switching to WPF to make this happen, I just haven't had occasion to until now.

Comment: @AlexWhittemore Just search for "WPF DataTemplate". You'll find plenty of examples.